# Can I Hide Certain Elements from Blogger Automatically from Previous Posts Using Javascript on the Fly?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, blogger, blogspot

I'll make a long story short, I have a blogger/blogspot blog. On every post I manually posted an ad inside the post in the form of a table. Now, I want to remove all of these ads. 
My question is, is it possible to do this with Javascript on the fly when the user loads the page without manually removing ads from every single blog post?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If the ads have a common class, for example, `ad`, you can use:

```
function killMe(el){
   el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
var els=document.getElementsByClassName('ad');
for(var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
    killMe(els[i]);
}
```

**Edit**:

Then, you can use

```
document.getElementsByClassName = document.getElementsByClassName || function(cName) {
    var arr=[],
        els=document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(var i=0,l=els.length;i<l;i++){
        if(els[i].className.split(' ').indexOf(cName)>-1){
            arr.push(els[i]);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
function killMe(el){
   el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
var els=document.getElementsByClassName('post-body');
for(var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
    killMe(els[i].getElementsByTagName('tr')[0]);
}
```

Comment: I've just checked the source code, and no it is not in a <div>. It is a raw table. The table itself have a 'ClassName', but it also have the body of the post as well as the part I want to remove. Anyway, thanks for your valuable help @Oriol :)

Comment: @Beshoy It doesn't matter if it's a `<div>` or a `<table>`. Then, do you mean that the table contains the ad and the body of the post (which you don't want to remove)?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant.
It is a table that have two tables, one for the ad and the other for the post body.

Comment: @Beshoy And does the part of the table which contains only the ad have a class?

Comment: @Beshoy But at least is there a pattern? For example, the first row. Can you post a link to your page?

Comment: here is a test blog with the same post structure used in the original blog, I'm using it for testing.
http://dynamic-javascript.blogspot.com/

Comment: By the way, it gives me an error when using the code snippet use posted above, here is the error:
**Error parsing XML, line 20, column 26: Element type "els.length" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".**

Comment: @I will look your site. But the error seems because the browser parses XML inside the `<scrip>`. To avoid it, create a `CDATA` section: `<script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/ [code] /*]]>*/</script>`

Comment: Thank you a lot for your precious help, I've done everything you said. I've put the code into a `<script>` tags once before the `Header` tag and the other after the `Body` tag, but it seems not to work for me. Thanks anyway for spending this time trying to help me. Thank you man :)